# How can I tell if I'm on WiFi versus Wired networking from a shell script?

Tags: network, command-line, wifi

I have written a script that does a periodic upload of a large file to the cloud. However, I do not want it to run unless I'm on wired networking.

Is there a way via the command line that you could determine if you're on wired versus wireless networking?

Comment: Look at which interfaces are up and which are down with ifconfig(1).